# Connect Angular-2

Tags: angularjs, angular, spring-boot

How do i can connect Angular-2 to spring-boot ?

I have link by angular-1, but that not work with

```
*ngFor
```

I have script to angular-1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:
I used Angular CLI for using Angular-2